# Web image download vs Web image to display in imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

In my application is like (Montage) to show a lot of images, videos , music and also to mainatain the image id for its own identification and other purpose. I need to know the **whether the all image is show using sdwebimage in imageview or after i logged in all images to download and saved it to local files** ? Tell me which is good ?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage is already providing caching mechanism, so instead of downloading all images at once use SDWebImage

SDWebImage also using lazy load, so the performance of your application will be good.

But if you try to download all images at once, it will degrade your app performance. You need to wait before loading view till downloading end.